# React-Redux FlatList Updation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an AuditionsList component which displays a FlatList. In a different reducer I'm changing Settings called location and roleType. Depending on these new settings I want to refresh the AuditionList.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AuditionItem from './AuditionItem';
import Auditions from './../data/Auditions';

class AuditionsList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [], refresh: false }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this._refreshData();
    }

    _onRefresh() {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true }, this._refreshData() );
    }

    _refreshData = () => {
        Auditions.fetchAuditions(this.props.productionType, this.props.location, this.props.roleType).then(auditions => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, data: this._addKeysToAuditions(auditions) });
        });
    }

    _addKeysToAuditions = auditions => {
      return auditions.map(audition => {
          return Object.assign(audition, { key: audition.Role});
      });
    }

    _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <AuditionItem
          auditionId={item.objectId}
          role={item.Role}
          project={item.Project.Name}
          productionType={item.Project.ProductionType.Type}
          auditionDate={JSON.stringify(item.Date.iso)}
          productionHouse={item.Project.ProductionHouse.Name}
        />
      );
    }

    render() {
      console.log("Here...");

      if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()} refreshing={this.state.isLoading} data={this.state.data} renderItem={this._renderItem} />
       </View>
      );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    location: state.settings.location,
    roleType: state.settings.roleType,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuditionsList);
```

I need to call the _onRefresh() or _refreshData() function AFTER the callback to mapStateToProps (which runs successfully) but BEFORE the FlatList re-renders (which also happens successfully, but with old data). So where do I call the _onRefresh() or _refreshData() functions? Putting them in render() causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the ComponentDidUpdate react lifecycle method? This will fire after you receive new props, and you could make a call to this._refreshData there.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Thanks v.much for your suggestion. I haven't been able to test it out since my Back4App api limit has been reached, but it seems to be the proper solution as it's not going into an infinite loop as in the other cases. I will install a parse-server locally and test it out and get back whether it actually gives the proper results. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I tested it out and your answer works perfectly. Thank you so much!